# Internal class objects not resetting after instantiating a custom class in Python 3.6

Tags: python, class, instance, instantiation, self

I am using `Python 3.6.4` and built a custom class where I'm doing a computation and changing one of the internal class variables.  I noticed it always runs correctly when I'm running the algorithm (e.g. instantiating class, etc.) and always failing the 2nd time.  Even if it's the same line code repeated twice in a row.  I've been able to replicate the error in it's more simple form.

**Why is the `lr_space` that is being changed in the first object propagating to the 2nd instantiated object?**

```
class testing(object):
    def __init__(self, 
                n_iter=5,
                n_space=10,
                model_type="logistic",
                lr_space={
                    "C":(1e-6, 1.0),
                    "penalty":["l1", "l2"],
                },
                lr_kws=dict(max_iter=10000, solver="liblinear"),
                ):
        self.n_iter = n_iter
        self.n_space = n_space
        # Logistic Regression
        self.lr_space = lr_space
        self.lr_kws = lr_kws
        print("", self, self.lr_space,"", sep="\n\t")
        self.model_type = model_type.lower()
        self.models = self._test_function()

    def _test_function(self):
        """
        Internal: Label models
        Need to extend this for using different hyperparameters
        """
        models = list()
        self.param_index = OrderedDict()

        # Indexing for hyperparameters and models
        a = np.ones(self.n_iter*2)
        b = np.arange(a.size)
        if self.model_type == "logistic":
            self.lr_space["C"] = np.linspace(*self.lr_space["C"], self.n_space)


        return models
print("=====Instantiating and running `instance_1`=====")
instance_1 = testing()
print("=====Instantiating and running `instance_2`=====")
instance_2 = testing()
```

Output:

```
=====Instantiating and running `instance_1`=====

    <__main__.testing object at 0x136154400>
    {'C': (1e-06, 1.0), 'penalty': ['l1', 'l2']}

=====Instantiating and running `instance_2`=====

    <__main__.testing object at 0x127649390>
    {'C': array([  1.00000000e-06,   1.11112000e-01,   2.22223000e-01,
         3.33334000e-01,   4.44445000e-01,   5.55556000e-01,
         6.66667000e-01,   7.77778000e-01,   8.88889000e-01,
         1.00000000e+00]), 'penalty': ['l1', 'l2']}
```

Error:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
         38 instance_1 = testing()
         39 print("=====Instantiating and running `instance_2`=====")
    ---> 40 instance_2 = testing()

```
<ipython-input-342-24f241984973> in __init__(self, n_iter, n_space, model_type, lr_space, lr_kws)
     17         print("", self, self.lr_space,"", sep="\n\t")
     18         self.model_type = model_type.lower()
---> 19         self.models = self._test_function()
     20 
     21     def _test_function(self):

<ipython-input-342-24f241984973> in _test_function(self)
     31         b = np.arange(a.size)
     32         if self.model_type == "logistic":
---> 33             self.lr_space["C"] = np.linspace(*self.lr_space["C"], self.n_space)
     34 
     35 

TypeError: linspace() takes from 2 to 6 positional arguments but 11 were given
```

Comment: Try assigning the default value of lr_space inside the init function instead. I.e. lr_space=None in definition, and then if lr_space is None: lr_space = lr_space={"C":(1e-6, 1.0), "penalty":["l1", "l2"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

If you assign the default value of lr_space inside the init function instead it works:

```
 from collections import OrderedDict
 import numpy as np

 class testing(object):
     def __init__(self, 
                 n_iter=5,
                 n_space=10,
                 model_type="logistic",
                 lr_space=None,
                 lr_kws=dict(max_iter=10000, solver="liblinear"),
                 ):
         if lr_space is None:
           lr_space = {
                     "C":(1e-6, 1.0),
                     "penalty":["l1", "l2"],
           }
         self.n_iter = n_iter
         self.n_space = n_space
         # Logistic Regression
         self.lr_space = lr_space
         self.lr_kws = lr_kws
         print("", self, self.lr_space,"", sep="\n\t")
         self.model_type = model_type.lower()
         self.models = self._test_function()

     def _test_function(self):
         """
         Internal: Label models
         Need to extend this for using different hyperparameters
         """
         models = list()
         self.param_index = OrderedDict()

         # Indexing for hyperparameters and models
         a = np.ones(self.n_iter*2)
         b = np.arange(a.size)
         if self.model_type == "logistic":
             self.lr_space["C"] = np.linspace(*self.lr_space["C"], self.n_space)


         return models
 print("=====Instantiating and running `instance_1`=====")
 instance_1 = testing()
 print("=====Instantiating and running `instance_2`=====")
 instance_2 = testing()
```

## Why:

When you assign default values to arguments in `def __init__(...)`, they are assigned **before** the new instance exists. This doesn't matter when using simple non-mutable values such as `5` and `"logistic"` but of you use a dict, you are creating a object outside of the instance and then assigning it to a reference in the `__init__` call.

This is a dangerous anti-pattern that you should avoid. You can read more about it here: [Using a mutable default value as an argument](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html)

When you create new instances, the reference is assigned again, but it's still referencing the same object. Your code above is equivalent to:

```
default_dict = {
    "C":(1e-6, 1.0),
    "penalty":["l1", "l2"],
}

class testing(object):
     def __init__(self, 
            n_iter=5,
            n_space=10,
            model_type="logistic",
            lr_space=default_dict,
            lr_kws=dict(max_iter=10000, solver="liblinear"),
            ):
```

Comment: This works too and it helped me address what actual problem was in the first place.  Thanks!

Comment: See: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html

Comment: Glad it worked @O.rka ! You might want to do the same for the lr_kws=dict(...) part. It will potentially lead to similar hard to find bugs down the road.

Comment: Thanks @jbch ! I added your link to my answer

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was using `deepcopy` from the `copy` built-in:

```
import copy
class testing(object):
    def __init__(self, 
                n_iter=5,
                n_space=10,
                model_type="logistic",
                lr_space={
                    "C":(1e-6, 1.0),
                    "penalty":["l1", "l2"],
                },
                lr_kws=dict(max_iter=10000, solver="liblinear"),
                ):
        self.n_iter = n_iter
        self.n_space = n_space
        # Logistic Regression
        self.lr_space = copy.deepcopy(lr_space)
        self.lr_kws = lr_kws
        print("", self, self.lr_space,"", sep="\n\t")
        self.model_type = model_type.lower()
        self.models = self._test_function()

    def _test_function(self):
        """
        Internal: Label models
        Need to extend this for using different hyperparameters
        """
        models = list()
        self.param_index = OrderedDict()

        # Indexing for hyperparameters and models
        a = np.ones(self.n_iter*2)
        b = np.arange(a.size)
        if self.model_type == "logistic":
            self.lr_space["C"] = np.linspace(*self.lr_space["C"], self.n_space)


        return models
```